# Are if statements possible in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This code works fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?seo_name=$1
```

But, I want to add if statements like this, is that possible and how?

```
if seo_name = cccc, go to page cccc.php

if seo_name = dddd, go to page dddd.php
```

and so forth and so on.

Thank you.

Ron

Comment: And you will write 100 `if`s? Maybe you just need a `$1.php` rewrite?

Comment: So is it _Ron_ or _Robbie_?

Comment: Why don't you include the right file in `index.php` based on the variable? Or better yet, use a database for the content. Saves you loads of pages and the trouble of editing `.htaccess` every time you add a new page...

Comment: do you want real ccc.php,ddd.php pages are virtual ones. the latter makes the most sense

Comment: real ones, ones with forms in it

Comment: Careful what you ask for... with Apache 2.4 you do indeed have `<If>` statements (as in conventional If...ElseIf...Else). However, you wouldn't use this construct to do what you are asking about... using mod_rewrite to rewrite/redirect specific URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RewriteRule` and take advantage of the regexes directly. I think they are enough to discriminate your pages.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1.php
```

Or if you just need specific pages to be replaced you can do like this:

```
RewriteRule ^mypage$ mypage.php
```

Note that you can even use these to pass query strings to php to discriminate directly in the source code, then a php if with `include()`s may do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^page([0-9]+)$ page.php?id=$1
```

Note that these URL replacements aren’t redirections and they’re not “seen” by the browser, so any relative file required by the html will be taken from the path of the virtual folder.

**EDIT:** my suggestion for you is to make htaccess to point to a php file (let's call it `hub.php`):

```
RewriteRule ^cccc$ hub.php?id=cccc
RewriteRule ^dddd$ hub.php?id=dddd
```

Now php will do the trick, in `hub.php`:

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 'cccc') {
   include('cccc.php');
}

if ($_GET['id'] == 'dddd') {
   include('dddd.php');
}
```

I think there are faaaaar better ways to do this, but if you prefer this way... And this will make it work without changing the code in cccc.php and dddd.php

Just pass the "great" jobs to php, don't make big .htaccess files (.htaccess modifications require Apache to reload, php files do not).

Comment: content is db content, i need it for the pages with forms in it.

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you want something like /user/x redirects to a page that asks the db for a content x?

Comment: seo_name is the url variable and the url name, like this: www.xxxx.com/seo_name without extension.

Comment: But the  form page is .php

Comment: so, it goes to the index.php, it have to go to form.php

Comment: in other words, to seo_name.php

Comment: but it goes to seo_name (index.php)
So my question, if seo_name is contact-form, got to contact-form.php

Comment: I see. the first solution I wrote should replace ANY file adding the php extension. But you don’t want ANY files to be replaced ain’t you? Now I’ll write an edit with what I’d do if I were you (which I also did in my projects).

Comment: Edited. See if it's what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it ans let you know!

Comment: Sure PHP will do the trick, I was on the wrong track, Thanks again Osna (-:

Comment: And PHP alone, i didn't need to change the htaccess file.